# Jenkins Pipepline is failing: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from XXX failed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins pipeline is failing while checking out from svn. Below is the error.

```
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from nobuild01.sdi.pvt/152.144.34.14:50396
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1036)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1025)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:928)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:864)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:85)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:75)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class jenkins.model.Jenkins
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.descriptor(SubversionSCM.java:2584)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.createDefaultSVNOptions(SubversionSCM.java:1085)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.createClientManager(SubversionSCM.java:1075)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1002)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:979)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2918)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from nobuild01.sdi.pvt/152.144.219.14:50396 failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:961)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1036)
Caused: java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: c:\Dev at hudson.remoting.Channel@4b1b30ed:JNLP4-connect connection from nobuild01.sdi.pvt/152.144.34.14:50396
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1043)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1025)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:928)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:864)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:85)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:75)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Slave machine is running on openJDK, not Oracle java. so I used IcedTea to run .jnlp.
I checked my Jenkins service is running.

openjdkverion: java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3

Also someone guild me where I can see the Jenkins log. I am running Jenkins master as a Docker container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. For Windows, go to Services (Start → Run: services.msc), find Jenkins and Jenkins Agent, right click → Restart.
2. If it does not help (UI is not responding) open the Windows Task Manager → Processes, kill the java.exe process, and restart the service once again.

```
ps -ef | grep jenkins
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to refSpec configuration on jenkins.  In Source Code management, provide the SSH,  github/any other git REPO URL .
Tap on Advanced Button and provide **"refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*"** in RefSpec

In above configuration bold content might be creating problem, please remove and restart your jenkins.

In my case this solved problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

We got the error in the title during "git clone", but not "NoClassDefFoundError" that follows. We solved the problem by shortening the job name.

It wasn't too long on its own, but the paths of files in the repository became too long when prepended with the folder name of the job. Apparently this intervened with the clone operation.